# How to calculate the reaction force of an object that has just flung out from an accelerating circular motion?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

If I am an astronaut floating in space and swirling the object with a string in my hand and then releasing it at 90 degrees relative to my front position, is my assumption correct that I would get a reaction force that is slightly angled (not parallel to the direction of the projectile perhaps forming like an inverse letter y)? How to calculate this?

Comment: If you are floating in space, then the object is swirling you also. You are not fixed or attached to anything so your momentum at any point has to be equal and opposite of the objects momentum, such that the sum is zero.

Comment: How is the plane of motion of the object relative to your "front" side?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thank you for your answer. To answer your question, it is horizontal to my front side.

Answer (score 1):

> is my assumption correct that I would get a reaction force that is slightly angled (not parallel to the direction of the projectile perhaps forming like an inverse letter y)?

No, this assumption is not correct. If you release the projectile so that it's trajectory is directly towards your front, then by conservation of momentum your trajectory will be directly towards your back.

Now, depending on your and the projectile's total angular momentum before the release, it is possible that you will have a bit of angular momentum and will spin after the release. It may be that whatever intuition was driving your original assumption was actually thinking about this spinning. This would depend very much on the details.